# Mirroring rows in matrix with loops/recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, matrix

Given some matrix, I need to mirror all the rows in the matrix. For example

```
[[2, 1],
[4, 3]]
```

would become

```
[[1, 2],
[3, 4]]
```

I managed to do it for the (2 x 2)-case. But I'm having trouble mirroring something like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

This has to become

```
[[4, 3, 2, 1],
[4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

I want to do this with loops/recursion. If I use recursion, I would probably have as basic step that the inner most elements get swapped first, and then from here on we would make the matrix bigger by also including the outer elements and swapping them too. However, I'm having trouble with the recursion step. After having swapped the inner most elements, I want to include the next to inner most elements in the matrix, and swap them too, and then continue like this until we reach the outer elements. How can this be implemented in code? This is what I did so far:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
          [1, 2, 3, 4]]

def mirror(matrix):
    # This corresponds to the basic step. The two inner most elements get swapped.
    if len(matrix) == 2:
        for i in range(len(matrix)):
            for j in range(len(matrix)):
                # Store one element in a temporal variable
                temp = matrix[i][j]
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][len(matrix) - 1]
                matrix[i][len(matrix)-1] = temp
                return matrix

    else:
        # Recursion step
        for i in range(len(matrix)):
            for j in range(len(matrix)):
                return (matrix + mirror(matrix[(len(matrix) // 2) - 1 : len(matrix)]))
```

The recursion step is wrong I think. I tried using the slice operator, but I'm not sure how this should be done correctly. Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be recursive?

Comment: Well, I've only studied loops, recursion, lists, search algorithms and functions with Python. So on the basis of my limited knowledge, I think recursion is the easiest/most efficient way to tackle this problem.

Comment: `[sub[::-1] for sub in arr]` is the simplest solution, do you want to change the original array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recursive solution is pretty trivial, just recurse across the array reversing each subarray:

```
arr= [[2, 1],
[4, 3]]

def reve(l):
    # if we have recursed across all sub arrays just return empty list
    if not l:
        return []
    # else reverse the first current sublist l[0] and recurse on the remaining sublists 
    return [l[0][::-1]] + reve(l[1:])


print(reve(arr))
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Which can be written concisely as:

```
def reve(l):
    return [l[0][::-1]] + reve(l[1:]) if l else []
```

If you wanted it *inplace*:

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [1, 2, 3, 4]]

def reve(l):
    if not l:
        return 
    # call inplace list.reverse on each sublist
    l[0].reverse()
    return reve(l[1:])


reve(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[4, 3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

And lastly we can achieve what you want *inplace* with no slicing at all using `iter` with the special method `__length__hint`:

```
def reve(l):
    if l.__length_hint__() == 0:
        return 
    sub = next(l)
    sub.reverse()
    return reve(l)


reve(iter(arr))

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[4, 3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your code. What does [l[0] [:: -1]] + reve(l[1: ]) do? Is this the recursion step that looks only at the two inner most elements, and swaps these?

Comment: @Kamil, `l[0]` is each sublist as we recurse across the list passed in starting from the first, ` reve(l[1: ])`  moves across the list, l[1:], l[2:]... until l == []

Answer (score 2):

Both functions might use the [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function, but you can use a imperative `for` also. About my recursive approach, the else statement refers to all cases between the ultimate and second elements of the list, they are being concatenated until the first element is reached.

My recursive approach:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], 
     [5, 6, 7]]

def mirror(matrix):
    def revert(row):
        if len(row) == 1:
            return [row[0]]
        else:
            return [row[-1]] + revert(row[:-1]) # concatenates two lists.

    return [revert(row) for row in matrix]

mirror(a)
```

My declarative approach:

```
def mirror(matrix):
    def revert(row):
        return row[::-1] # copies the array in reverse order

    return list(map(revert, matrix)) #<-for python3, and just map(...) for python2

mirror(a)
```

Both functions outputs

`[[3, 2, 1], [7, 6, 5]]`

Comment: This code does not work for me. It says 'map object at 0x12343' or something. I don't understand your 'else' step in the recursive approach, and also what does map do? Bear in mind I'm only a beginner with Python.

Comment: @Kamil what version of python are you using? and I added the map documentation, however the easiest way to think a `map` in python is by this `[A] => [B]`, where the length of both lists (A and B) are the same, and the arrow represents a modification of each element. However you can use a for instead of it, I will add the alternative soon.

Comment: Could the person who negatively voted, tell me the reason?

Comment: Not mine but the recursion seems to be way more complicated than it needs to be, your second  code also won't work for the OP using python3

Comment: @PadraicCunningham About the last part I agree, but I think he should have been more specific about the target version, besides I tried to make my recursive approach the most simple possible but looks like it wasn't achieved.

Comment: You need `return list(map(revert, matrix))` to workj for python3

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for your suggestion! I modified the code and added it.

Comment: Alberto, why do you return row[-1]  in your recursive approach? I don't understand the recursive step quite.

Comment: @Kamil that's the last element of a list in python so I am returning always the last element, until I reach the last one, in that case I  take last remaining element Note: I could have used row[-1] or row[0] inside the `if`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a more Pythonic way of doing that would be using list comprehensions. You can do that simply by:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
      [1, 2, 3, 4]]
reversed_matrix = (i[::-1] for i in matrix)
```

reversed_matrix will be a generator expression. You may convert it into a list by replacing "()" with "[]" In the list comprehension.

`i[::-1]` reverses the array in-place using slice operator